# Bad Date object output

Tags: java, date, time, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert my time object into string but it's only works on january

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Long l = ((int)properties.get("time") * 1000L) - 2*3600*1000L;

 String date1 = sdf.format(l);
 System.out.println(date1);`

and the output is like:

```
2015-02-32 00:00:02 
2015-02-32 00:00:02 
2015-02-32 00:00:02 
2015-02-32 00:00:02
```

As you can see i'm getting "32" on the day

Thnx

Comment: What is the value of `properties.get("time")`? Don't leave out important details like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an Overflow on your Long-Value.
Check your **properties.get("time")** value